# SQL Server: is it to drop a SQL Server 2005 by sqlcmd or set an instance to SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have a problem I have an instance called `SQLEXPRESS` previously created by SQL Server 2005 Express.

Now it is uninstalled but it didn't remove the instance.

How can I remove it and after to create it with an instance of SQL Server 2012?

The instance is: `AC5099\SQLEXPRESS`

Thanks

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Try the DBA site.

Comment: You can't uninstall the instance but not remove it. If you uninstalled parts of the instance (E.g. tools, books, client components), that's different from uninstalling the instance which typically means uninstalling the engine. If you successfully uninstalled the engine but still see the instance as one of the available services in Configuration Manager or in the Windows Services applet, that probably means your uninstall either failed or you uninstalled the wrong engine. Also, this should go to dba.stackexchange.com.